# Use existing migrations tables for laravel unit testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, laravel-5

I want to use an existing set of migrations to create tables for me to stuff seed data into. I am using [Orchestra Testbench](https://github.com/orchestral/testbench) for testing. [Examples like this](https://github.com/adamwathan/eloquent-oauth/blob/master/tests/FunctionalTestCase.php) show creating the table on the fly:

`DB::schema()->create('oauth_identities', function($table) {...`

But I want to use existing migrations.

**TestCase.php:**

```
use Orchestra\Testbench\TestCase as OrchestraTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends OrchestraTestCase
{
    protected function getBasePath()
    {
        // reset base path to point to our package's src directory
        return __DIR__ . '/../vendor/orchestra/testbench/fixture';
    }
}
```

**DBTestCase.php:**

class DBTestCase extends TestCase
{
    protected $artisan;

```
/*
 * Bootstrap the application
 */
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->artisan = $this->app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel');

    $this->artisan('migrate', [
            '--database' => 'testbench',
            '--realpath' => realpath(__DIR__.'/../database/migrations'),
        ]
    );

}

protected function getEnvironmentSetUp($app)
{
    parent::getEnvironmentSetUp($app);

    $app['config']->set('database.default', 'testbench');
    $app['config']->set('database.connections.testbench', [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => ':memory:',
            'prefix'   => ''
        ]
    );
}
```

**UserTest.php:**

```
class UserTest extends DBTestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

   private function seedUser()
   {

       return [
           'email' => 'myemail',
            ...
       ];
       ...
   }

...
public function testCreateUser()
{
    $user = User::create($this->seedUser());

    die(print_r($user)); 
    ...
```

Error:

> In \App\Tests\UserTest::testCreateUser
>   General error: 1 no such table: users

But in my migrations, I am definitely creating the table:

`Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {...`

So how can I use existing migration tables and generate seed data for the migration?

---

Edit: now when running `phpunit` after setting my DB driver in DBTestCase, `'driver'   => 'sqlite',`, it throws error:

> Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOSqlite\Driver' not found in .../Database/SQLiteConnection.php

Navigating to `SQLiteConnection.php`, the `PDOSqlite` in `use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOSqlite\Driver as DoctrineDriver;` is highlighted in red, saying it's an undefined namespace.

I have this available as a driver in my database.php:

**Database.php:**

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlite',
        'database' => storage_path('database.sqlite'),
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have setup the `ServiceProvider` correctly in your package and also pointed to your migration files with `loadMigrationsFrom` inside the `boot` method, then you just need to change your test class like this:

```
class TestCase extends \Orchestra\Testbench\TestCase
{
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->artisan('migrate', ['--database' => 'testbench'])->run();
    }

    /**
     * add the package provider
     *
     * @param $app
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getPackageProviders($app)
    {
        return [\Vendor\Your-Packagename::class];
    }


    /**
     * Define environment setup.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Foundation\Application  $app
     * @return void
     */
    protected function getEnvironmentSetUp($app)
    {
        // Setup default database to use sqlite :memory:
        $app['config']->set('database.default', 'testbench');
        $app['config']->set('database.connections.testbench', [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => ':memory:',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Laravel 5 you can set up your test cases to use data migrations like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    /**
     * A basic functional test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $this->visit('/')
             ->see('Laravel 5');
    }
}
```

By using the `DatabaseMigration` trait the database is migrated before each test case and **rolled back after it**. Please remember this if you try testing the same data in different test cases.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for this. Even after using the `DatabaseMigrations` Trait, it throws `Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOSqlite\Driver not found in /Users/.../Database/SQLiteConnection.php`

Comment: Did you define a test connection in your database.php?

Comment: A composer dependency is missing: `"doctrine/dbal": "~2.3"`